# Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Tags: php

I'm building a project with angular and php, and I'm trying to delete a row from phpmyadmin table, and I have this error in php. can anyone please check my code?

```
  <?php
     header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    $connect=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "hamatkin");

      include_once 'file.php';
    mysqli_query($connect,"SET character_set_client = utf8");
    mysqli_query($connect,"SET character_set_connection = utf8");
    mysqli_query($connect,"SET character_set_results = utf8");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));


     $id = $data->id;
    $del = "DELETE FROM file WHERE id=".$id;

       mysqli_query($connect, $del);

    $newURL = "/hamatkin/#/allPriceOffers";
    header('Location: '.$newURL);
    ?>
```

after using var_dump($data):

```
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<small>C:\wamp64\www\hamatkin\api\customers-tab\delete-priceOffer.php:43:</small>
<b>object</b>(<i>stdClass</i>)[<i>2</i>]
  <i>public</i> 'id' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> 
    <b>object</b>(<i>stdClass</i>)[<i>3</i>]
      <i>public</i> 'created' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'2016-08-11 15:19:14'</font> <i>(length=19)</i>
      <i>public</i> 'customer_id' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'85'</font> <i>(length=2)</i>
      <i>public</i> 'full_name' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'אלכס שפירא'</font> <i>(length=19)</i>
      <i>public</i> 'city' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'תל-אביב'</font> <i>(length=13)</i>
      <i>public</i> 'phone' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'545928875'</font> <i>(length=9)</i>
      <i>public</i> 'name' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'×§×•×¨×•×ª ×—×™×™×.zip'</font> <i>(length=46)</i>
```

Comment: On what line does the error say is the issue?

Comment: I think you are getting null in $data variable just var_dump($data) and see the output

Comment: @Ben on line :  $del = "DELETE FROM file WHERE id=".$id;

Comment: @Tanyaa In that case, use `var_dump($data)` to see what `$id` is - it looks like it's not a string variable but an object.

Comment: First of all try to use PHP PDO. if it is not possible, at least use `mysqli_escape_string()` for parameters used in SQL queries.

Comment: @Ben thanks for helping! i will edit the question to show you whar "var_dump($data) output

Comment: @Andrew I didn't understand you completly

Comment: @Ben you are right ,but lets figure out what she is getting in `$data`

Comment: @aman what do you think i should do?

Comment: @tanyaa `var_dump($data)` is confusing do this `var_dump(file_get_contents("php://input"))` and show us what you are getting

Comment: $id = $data->id->customer_id; your id is an object containing 6 other fields (strings). Posted as answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php)

Comment: @M.I now i have no errors ! but still doesn't delete

Comment: @M.I. I'm customer_id is a foreign key in that table called:"refer_customer_id"

Comment: @tanyaa What does the error say?
$del = "DELETE FROM file WHERE id=$id";

var_dump($del). and check if the id is the correct one and try to list in in phpmyadmin or from the php file:
var_dump(mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM file WHERE id=$id");

Comment: Try debugging as much as you can, and you will find the error.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$id = intval($data->id->customer_id);
```

Does the new edit help?

Comment: thanks but still the same no errors but not deleting

Comment: @tanyaa  Where do you want to delete from, you have more than one table? your database field is customer_id, unless customer_id is a foreign key in file table you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
json_decode($data, true)
```

> mixed **json_decode** ( string $json [, bool **$assoc** = false [, int $depth = 512 [, int $options = 0 ]]] )
>
> **accs** When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

See Document [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).